# My function to convert jsonString into a Object doesn't work

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I create an `AsyncTask` on my android project and I'm getting info from a json web service but in this specific function I can't get the proper return already checked JSONLint and I'm getting a valid `jsonString` and on other `AsyncTask` I'm able to deserialize into the same class with GSON

If I call any getter from the object `curso` will return `null`

```java
public class DetalheCursoService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Curso> {

    @Override
    protected Curso doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {

            String jsonString = GET(urls[0]);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            Log.i("teste", jsonString);
            if(jsonString.substring(11,15).equals("true")){

                jsonString = "{" + jsonString.substring(16);

                Log.i("teste", jsonString);
                Type cursoType = Curso.class;
                Curso curso = gson.fromJson(jsonString, cursoType);
                String teste = ""+ curso.getCod_curso();
                Log.i("teste", teste);
                return curso;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough information. What's the JSON string? What's `Curso`?

Comment: Are you seeing an exception being thrown? You might be missing the fact that `e.printStackTrace()` is actually being called.

Comment: Also, if you're able to do this elsewhere, why not just re-use that code? Parsing the JSON in this way seems odd and fragile. How can you be sure it starts at position 16 in the String? Wouldn't a value of `false` cause it to break? If `Curso` is encapsulated in something else, you should deserialize the entire JSON string instead of parsing the string first.